# Representing every positive rational number in the form of $(a^n+b^n)/(c^n+d^n)$

Tags: nt.number-theory

About a month ago, I got the following :

> For **every positive rational number** $r$, there exists a set of four **positive integers** $(a,b,c,d)$ such that 
>   $$r=\frac{a^\color{red}{3}+b^\color{red}{3}}{c^\color{red}{3}+d^\color{red}{3}}.$$
>
> For $r=p/q$ where $p,q$ are positive integers, we can take 
>   $$(a,b,c,d)=(3ps^3t+9qt^4,\ 3ps^3t-9qt^4,\ 9qst^3+ps^4,\ 9qst^3-ps^4)$$
>   where $s,t$ are positive integers such that $3\lt r\cdot(s/t)^3\lt 9$.
>
> For $r=2014/89$, for example, since we have $(2014/89)\cdot(2/3)^3\approx 6.7$, taking $(p,q,s,t)=(2014,89,2,3)$ gives us $$\frac{2014}{89}=\frac{209889^3+80127^3}{75478^3+11030^3}.$$

Then, I began to try to find **every positive integer** $n$ such that the following proposition is true :

**Proposition** : For every positive rational number $r$, there exists a set of four positive integers $(a,b,c,d)$ such that $$r=\frac{a^\color{red}{n}+b^\color{red}{n}}{c^\color{red}{n}+d^\color{red}{n}}.$$

The followings are what I've got. Let $r=p/q$ where $p,q$ are positive integers.

- For $n=1$, the proposition is true. We can take $(a,b,c,d)=(p,p,q,q)$.
- For $n=2$, the proposition is **false**. For example, no such sets exist for $r=7/3$.
- For even $n$, the proposition is **false** because the proposition is false for $n=2$.

However, I've been facing difficulty in the case of odd $n\ge 5$. I've tried to get a similar set of four positive integers $(a,b,c,d)$ to the set for $n=3$, but I have not been able to get any such set. So, here is my question.

> **Question** : How can we find **every odd number** $n\color{red}{\ge 5}$ such that the following proposition is true?
>
> **Proposition** : For every positive rational number $r$, there exists a set of four positive integers $(a,b,c,d)$ such that $$r=\frac{a^n+b^n}{c^n+d^n}.$$

I would like to know any relevant references as well.

**Remark** : This question has been asked previously on [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1185535/representing-every-positive-rational-number-in-the-form-of-anbn-cndn) without receiving any answers.

Comment: A reference for the original problem: IMO 1999 Shortlist, problem N2.

Comment: Why do you believe at first place that there exist $n\geq 5$ such that EVERY positive rational can be represented?

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas: I didn't mean I believe so. I meant I would like to know if the proposition is true for odd $n\ge 5$.

Comment: The question asks whether the projective surface $S_{n,r} \colon a^n + b^n = r(c^n + d^n)$ has rational points outside the line $a+b = c+d = 0$ for every $r \in {\mathbb Q}^\times$ (the case $r = 0$ is trivial). For $n \ge 5$, this is a surface of general type; it is expected to have only finitely many rational points outside the line, and I would think it likely that it frequently fails to have any such points. A proof might be difficult, though: the presence of the line means that arguments using congruences will not be able to exclude such points.

Comment: Actually, the requirement is stronger, since $a,b,c,d$ should be positive. The fact that the problem shows up on an IMO shortlist is somewhat suspicious...

Comment: @Michael Stoll The problem shows up only for the case $n=3$

Comment: If $p$ prim and $p-1|2n$ we have $a^n\equiv -1,0$ or $1 (\mod p )$. Hence if $r=e/f$, $e\not\equiv 0$, $f\not\equiv 0 (\mod p )$ and $ev \not\equiv fu$ for $u,v \in \{-2,-1,1,2\}$ we must have $a^n+b^n\equiv c^n+d^n\equiv 0 (\mod p )$.

Comment: @user35593: This is what I meant: you always have the points on the line(s) mod $p$. The problem is that knowing that $a^n+b^n \equiv c^n+d^n \equiv 0 \bmod p$ doesn't tell you anything about the quotient $(a^n+b^n)/(c^n+d^n)$...